# Speeding up System.Collection.Generic.Queue() possible?

Tags: c#

50\% of my simulation time is spent on the following code:

```
    internal double simWithdrawalFast(double t)
    {
        simarrivals.Enqueue(t + Leadtime);
        return simarrivals.Dequeue();
    }
```

where simarrivals is a `System.Collection.Generic.Queue<double>`.

If I write my own queue, will it be faster?

EDIT: note that there are doubles in the queue to begin with, i.e. the queue has about 200 elements when simwithdrawal is called. Each call adds and removes an element.

Comment: Aside: Style guidelines would dictate that the parameter name be `t`, because parameter names should be in lower-camel-case.  Because `T` is commonly used as the type parameter for a generic type or method with only one type parameter, using `T` for the method's formal parameter is a bit confusing.

Comment: @phoog: Or, even better, `time`. Give the variable a very meaningful name.

Comment: Do you specify an initial size for the Queue? If you've got 200 items to begin with, perhaps 256 would be a nice starting size, i.e. `new Queue<double>(256)`. That would shave memory reallocations.

Comment: @Jason yes, of course! I overlooked that obvious comment because I was so confused by my initial reading of the code as adding `LeadTime` to a type parameter.

Comment: Is `LeadTime` a field or a simple property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementations of these two methods seem pretty minimalist to me:

```
public T Dequeue()
{
  if (this._size == 0)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EmptyQueue);
  T obj = this._array[this._head];
  this._array[this._head] = default (T);
  this._head = (this._head + 1) % this._array.Length;
  --this._size;
  ++this._version;
  return obj;
}


public void Enqueue(T item)
{
  if (this._size == this._array.Length)
  {
    int capacity = (int) ((long) this._array.Length * 200L / 100L);
    if (capacity < this._array.Length + 4)
      capacity = this._array.Length + 4;
    this.SetCapacity(capacity);
  }
  this._array[this._tail] = item;
  this._tail = (this._tail + 1) % this._array.Length;
  ++this._size;
  ++this._version;
}
```

I have a hard time believing the semantics of a queue can be honored by code much more efficient than this.  Therefore, your problem is probably at a higher level.  Why is this method (`simWithdrawalFast`) getting called so much?  You're probably going to have to find a way to make your overall algorithm more efficient rather than finding a more efficient data structure.

If the problem is frequent resizing of the queue, you *might* be able to improve the performance somewhat by specifying a `capacity` when constructing the queue.  My hunch though is that this isn't your problem.

Comment: The code is part of a Monte-Carlo simulation. That's why it is run so often. The straightforward Monte-Carlo implementation of the system converges slowly.. So it is either speeding this function up, or using variance reduction..

Comment: If this code really is the bottleneck you could make some significant savings though. Like 50% or so.

Comment: I allready set the right capacity when initializing the Queue. I guess the answer is no, as you say. My problem is that Monte Carlo does not converge fast enough for this problem.

Comment: @Henk, by getting rid of the increment operations?  Wouldn't the cost of the method calls themselves significantly outweigh any potential cost savings on optimizing those individual operations?

Comment: The error and size checks, the _version and default(T) stuff. OK, maybe not 50%, but close. Ah, like in  @johnfisher's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Kirk's answer is great.  However, if you really need to speed this up, you can.

Copy the functions Kirk generously showed to you, then remove the checks or management that you do not need.  For example, if the code you posted is the *only* access to this queue, you could improve speed with something like the following.

```
private double[] array; // Initialize this appropriately.

public double Dequeue()
{
  // Assume you use these functions properly, and avoid the exception checks.
  double obj = this._array[this._head];

  // No need to clean up after ourselves if used appropriately...
  //this._array[this._head] = default (T);

  // Still need to adjust the position in the queue.
  this._head = (this._head + 1) % this._array.Length;

  // May not need these either.
  //--this._size;
  //++this._version;
  return obj;
}


public void Enqueue(T item)
{
  // Don't bother trying to resize if you know you don't ever need to.

  this._array[this._tail] = item;
  this._tail = (this._tail + 1) % this._array.Length;

  // Probably don't need these.
  //++this._size;
  //++this._version;
}
```

Also, if you **really** want to squeeze out performance, see if you can find a slightly faster set of operations to accomplish the same goal as the head and tail adjustments.  You can also look at C#'s `unchecked` keyword to see if it is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how much one could actually optimize this.  Method call operations (the `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` calls themselves) are one of the most expensive operations in IL, and nothing we can do can optimize *that*, unfortunately.  Still, it'd be interesting to test and see the results.

Comment: The methods are small enough to be inlined (manually) in `simWithdrawalFast()`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to know what could be achieved by combining these ideas, and inlining. I did not make explicit in the question that the length of the queue stays constant. So I can use a fixed array
simarrivalsArray with length simS:

The below adaptation makes the function twice as fast (i.e. fraction of time spent in function drops from 50 to 33\%):

```
internal double simWithdrawalFast(double time)
{
    double returnValue = simarrivalsArray[head]; //Withdrawal
    simarrivalsArray[head] = time+leadtime; //Enqueue
    head = (head + 1) % simS;//simS is length of array/queue, which stays constant;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now the crazy part: getting rid of modulus sign drops the fraction of time spent in this function to only 17\%. This means the function becomes about five times as fast as the original, or 2.5 times as fast as the version above (0.2/(1+0.2 ) is about 0.17).

```
internal double simWithdrawalFast(double time)
{
    double returnValue = simarrivalsArray[head]; //Withdrawal
    simarrivalsArray[head++] = time+leadtime; //Enqueue
    if(head==simS)//simS is length of array/queue, which stays constant;
    {
         head=0;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

EDIT: in response to HH, I wrote the some code to test the difference in isolation.

Output:

Own implementation:  7964
Queue:  23860

Factor of 3, but of course some time is spent in the loop itself. Profiling with slimtune gives me
Loop: 23%
Own implementation 11%
Queue: 65%
i.e. a factor 6.5.

I don't think it is the measuring overhead, as running the program while profiling gives me
Output:
Own implementation:  8795
Queue:  27863

Implementation:

```
class Tester
{
    int simS;
    Queue<double> simarrivals;
    double[] simarrivalsArray;
    int head = 0;
    double leadtime = 5.0;

    internal Tester()
    {
        this.simS = 300;
        simarrivalsArray = new double[simS];
        simarrivals = new Queue<double>(simS + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < simS; i++)
        {
            simarrivals.Enqueue(0.0);
        }            
    }

    internal void TestQueues()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        double withdrawals = 5.0E+8;
        for (double d = 0.0; d < withdrawals; d += 1.0)
        {
            simWithdrawalFast(d);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Own implementation:  "+ sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (double d = 0.0; d < withdrawals; d += 1.0)
        {
            simWithdrawalFast2(d);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Queue:  "+sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    double simWithdrawalFast(double time)
    {
        double returnValue = simarrivalsArray[head]; //Withdrawal 
        simarrivalsArray[head++] = time + leadtime; //Enqueue 
        if (head == simS)//simS is length of array/queue, which stays constant; 
        {
            head = 0;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    double simWithdrawalFast2(double t)
    {
        simarrivals.Enqueue(t + leadtime);
        return simarrivals.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Coming to think of it, why are these modulus calculations in the implementation of queue? Can't they be replaced by if statements, if these are so much faster?

Comment: Your results are interesting but I think they might also be related to some measuring artifacts. 5x seems odd, are head an SIMS normal `int`s?

Comment: I don't thinks these are measuring artifact. I created and added a minimum working example.